# Site Home page appearing as Mobile Page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I wanted to remove the title from appearing on the default 'Home' site by navigating to Site settings > Title, Description & Logo, clearing the 'Title' field and clicking save.

I didn't receive any error messages or warnings. My site home page seems to have been converted to a mobile page with limited editing options and everything I had added to it is now gone.

I can't seem to find how to switch it back to a regular web page. Any ideas on how to switch this back would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So got Microsoft on the job for this one... turns out a new Mobile page had been created and set as my default homepage.  Not sure how this happened as I did not select to create a new page for the site page.  My original page was listed within 'Site contents' and then 'Site Pages'.  I opened the link and set it as my default homepage - all now back to normal.